# ElasticSearch EngineException[Couldn't resolve version] nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I got the following exception, when I tried to update some records, I never seen this exception in ES before, please help:

```
2016-05-15 20:27:04][INFO ][rest.suppressed] /index1/aprelease/1122/_update Params: 
{id=aa22, index=index1, type=aprelease}
RemoteTransportException[[test-es15-a][indices:data/write/update[s]]]; 
nested: EngineException[Couldn't resolve version]; nested:
NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Input/output error: 
NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data/node-a/data/ts-data/nodes/0/indices/index1/18/index/_ypk3.cfs")
[slice=_ypk3_Lucene50_0.tim]]; 
nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Input/output error];

    Caused by: [index1][[index1][18]] EngineException[Couldn't resolve version]; 
    nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Input/output error:
    NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data/node-a/data/ts-data/nodes/0/indices/index1/18/index/_ypk3.cfs") 
    [slice=_ypk3_Lucene50_0.tim]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Input/output error];
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.Engine.getFromSearcher(Engine.java:256)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.get(InternalEngine.java:349)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.get(IndexShard.java:606)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.get.ShardGetService.innerGet(ShardGetService.java:173)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.get.ShardGetService.get(ShardGetService.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:76)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:170)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:164)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:65)
        at ....
```

Per Val's suggestion, I ran the following command and get the following result:

```
curl -XGET 'http://192.168.0.1:9200/index1/_upgrade?pretty&human'
{
  "size" : "408.4gb",
  "size_in_bytes" : 438558561139,
  "size_to_upgrade" : "0b",
  "size_to_upgrade_in_bytes" : 0,
  "size_to_upgrade_ancient" : "0b",
  "size_to_upgrade_ancient_in_bytes" : 0,
  "indices" : {
    "index1" : {
      "size" : "408.4gb",
      "size_in_bytes" : 438558561139,
      "size_to_upgrade" : "0b",
      "size_to_upgrade_in_bytes" : 0,
      "size_to_upgrade_ancient" : "0b",
      "size_to_upgrade_ancient_in_bytes" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you upgraded ES to a latter version recently? Can you run this as update your question with the output you get? `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index1/_upgrade?pretty&human'`

Comment: Hi Val, will ES automatically reallocate shards, I saw one of ES shards is relocating, but I didn't issue any command.

Comment: Ok, it's not an upgrade issue apparently.

Comment: I got the exception log: Input/output error: NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data/node-a/data/ts-data/nodes/0/indices/index1/18/index/_ypk3.cfs", so do you think is the 18th shard broken.

Comment: Can you show what you get when running `curl localhost:9200/_cat/shards` ?

Comment: I tried update other records on the same index, it worked well. So I guess some shards broken, but when I _cat/health it shows everything good. what do you think please.

Comment: `_cat/shards` not `_cat/health`

Comment: yes, _cat/shards still shows every good as I posted above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112075/discussion-between-jack-and-val).